# Can I change the text color of one link on a page that has been created by a script code?

Tags: hyperlink, colors, textcolor

I am using a code on my blog that is contained within `<script> </script>` tags, that when looking at the page, creates a link. My overall blog code sets a color for all links but I want this link to be a different color than all the rest.

I tried using a few different methods of changing the text color and even of changing the link color but nothing I tried worked.

Comment: Please show the code.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to see what you are doing wrong without seeing your code, but basically all you will need to do is set the color of your link with the `style` attribute when inserting the HTML, something like `style="color:red"`.

Assuming you are using pure JavaScript and your script looks something like this, this will give you a red link:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML += 
    '<a href="www.example.com" style="color:red">'This is red!'</a>';
```

If you are using jQuery your script may look something like this:

```
$('<a href="www.example.com" style="color:red">This is red!</a>').appendTo($('body'));
```

Inline styles have the highest priority of all CSS so these will override any other CSS you may have.

Leave a comment and update your question with your code if this doesn't help you, and I will try to improve this answer!